# JavaScript - Loop Through Array Directly In Multi Line String and Include Values

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, loops

Let's say I have an array called users.

```
const users = ["userOne", "userTwo"];
```

Within an ES6 multi-line string, I would like to loop through the array and include the values of the `users` array within the multi-line string.

I have tried giving it a go using the following code snippet:

```
const data = `

Hello,

The following users exist within the users array:

- ${users.forEach((item) => item)},
`
```

The expected outcome I would like it something like this:

```
Hello,

The following users exist within the users array:

- userOne
- userTwo
```

What would I need to do to loop through the array and include the values within the string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could map the items with some formatting.

```js
const users = ["userOne", "userTwo"];
const data = `Hello,

The following user${users.length > 1 ? 's' : ''} exist within the user's array:

${users.map(item => `- ${item}`).join(',\n')}`

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Ah I didn't think about the `.join(',\n')`. That's useful! Thank you :) This work.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```js
const users = ["userOne", "userTwo"];

const data = `Hello, The following users exist within the users array:
${users.map((user) => {
    return '- ' + user + '\n';
})}`

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Yes, this is similar to the response below :) This is right so will upvote but as the below answer was first + formats the response better I will mark that one as correct. :) Thanks though!

Comment: Oh yea maybe we're at the same time. Np!

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` instead of `forEach` and join with delimitter `'- '`

```js
const users = ["userOne", "userTwo"];


const data = `

Hello,
The following users exist within the user's array:

- ${users.map(item => item +'\n').join('- ')}`;

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `users.map()` instead of `users.forEach()`, because `map` returns a new array, `forEach` doesn't.